# Alternative to Geometry.IsValidDetailed()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, spatial-query

Is there an alternative method that I can use to get a detailed message on why a Geometry is invalid?

[Geometry.IsValidDetailed()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/isvaliddetailed-geometry-datatype?view=sql-server-2017) is not available in `SQL Server 2008 R2`, so I need a work around to get this message.

**Here is an example:**

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 (I am on Service Pack 2).

Create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GeoTests](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Geo] [geometry] NULL
)
```

Insert this invalid polygon into the table:

```
INSERT INTO GeoTests (
        Value, 
        Geo
    ) VALUES (
        'Polygon', 
        Geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((99 99 0, 99 100 0, 100 100 0, 99 100 0, 98 100 0, 99 99 0))', 0)
    )
```

You can tell the polygon is invalid using this:

```
SELECT Geo.STIsValid() FROM GeoTests
```

This is what I have so far for selecting the error message:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
        ,[Value]
        ,[Geo].STGeometryType()
    FROM [Tests].[dbo].[
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    PRINT ERROR_NUMBER()
END CATCH
```

*The problem is that the Error_Message() is generic and just shows that the Geometry is invalid, not any detail as to why.*

Is there any way while using `SQL Server 2008 R2` to get a similar error to [Geo.IsValidDetailed()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/isvaliddetailed-geometry-datatype?view=sql-server-2017) a function which was implemented in `SQL Server 2012`?